# How to avoid "not in" when updating a table of a multitable join in PostgreSQL

Tags: database, postgresql, sql-update

I've been staring at this for a while. The below function does work to correctly label the "noshow" column of the appointments table. But I've read where using "NOT IN" is slow...is there a better way? Perhaps with a left join?

TIA

PostgreSQL 9.3

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION g_update_noshow(groupid text)
  RETURNS void AS
$BODY$  

update appointments a
set noshow = 'true'
from patients pt
where 
    pt.groupid = $1                and
    a.patient_recid = pt.recid     and
    a.tappointment::date not in 
    ( select tencounter::date 
      from encountertimes et
      join patients p on et.patient_recid = p.recid 
      where et.notseen ='false' and p.groupid = $1);

$BODY$
  LANGUAGE sql VOLATILE
  COST 100;
ALTER FUNCTION g_update_noshow(text)
  OWNER TO postgres;
```

Comment: "*I have read that NOT IN is slow*" - and **is** your update slow? If it is, then **edit** your question and add the execution plan of the query (ideally the output of `explain analyze`). If it's not, then why do you want to change it?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I have nothing to compare it against. I'm only going by what I've read on other questions and earlier blogs. :)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Thanks. Did not know about explain analyze. :)

Answer (score 1):

Standard way to avoid `NOT IN(...)` is to use `NOT EXISTS(...)`. Standard reason to prefer `(not) exists` is that it behaves nicer if NULLs are involved in the matchfield(s).

```
UPDATE appointments a
SET noshow = 'true'
FROM patients pt
WHERE a.patient_recid = pt.recid
AND a.noshow IS DISTINCT FROM 'true' -- I added this to avoid needless updates
AND pt.groupid = $1
AND NOT EXISTS ( SELECT * 
        FROM encountertimes et
        JOIN patients p2 ON et.patient_recid = p2.recid
        WHERE et.tencounter::date = a.tappointment::date 
        AND et.notseen = 'false'
        AND p2.groupid = $1
        ) ;
```

Comment: I like this much better then mine. Clear and to the point. :)

Comment: Yours had the problem of referring to a column in the left-joined table (et.notseen = 'false') IIRC.